# JMeter with Custom Java Code

Tags: jmeter

I am new to JMeter and trying out certain sample code as part of my POC's. My requirement is pretty simple, I just need to attach a zip file to a SOAP message and fire the request. But to create the SOAP message we already have a framework that needs to be used. Now the problem I am facing is to include the framework JARs. I tried to add the library files into the project and create a JAR and paste it in /lib/ext folder and also by putting them in the class path. None of this works.

How do you use any existing framework JARs with the custom code you write for JMeter??

Answer (score 2):

1. Drop your jar to /lib folder of your JMeter installation
2. **Restart JMeter**. JMeter doesn't pick up new libraries or configuration file changes dynamically.
3. In [Beanshell](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_Sampler) or [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) refer to your jar classes as:

   ```
   import com.yourcompany.package.SomeClass;
   import com.yourcompany.package.SomeMessage;

   SomeClass myClass = new SomeClass(parameter1, parameter2);
   SomeMessage message = myClass.createMessage();
   message.send();
   ```

See [WebSocket Testing With Apache JMeter](http://blazemeter.com/blog/websocket-testing-apache-jmeter) guide as an example of using external jars in JMeter.