# How to Encrypt the Password Parameter in login screen in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I Have created a Jmeter Script and I'm trying to login to the application.

When I try to run the script I'm getting `invalid credentials` in the response.

The Password is encrypted in the Website which I'm trying to run.

The Password which i'm trying to pass is not been encrypted when seen in Response window.

Can someone suggest how to take Encrypted value from Password in Jmeter?

Comment: Can you should what you trying to send? how the value encrypted? do you really send to server value encrypted?

Comment: Im Passing the actual Password ie(Password@1) , the application encrypt it with MD5 algorithm along with the seed value and sends it to the server.

Comment: When saving a password verifier just using a hash function is not sufficient and just adding a salt does little to improve the security. Instead iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use a function such as `PBKDF2`, `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`, `password_hash`, `Bcrypt`, `passlib.hash` or similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a substantial of time finding passwords by brute force.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on encryption algorithm you can use i.e.

- [__base64Encode() function](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/#base64Encodesupfont-color-gray-size-1-since-1-2-0-font-sup)
- [__MD5() function](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/#MD5supfont-color-gray-size-1-since-0-4-2-font-sup)

Both functions are available via [JMeter Plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/) project and can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

[image: JMeter Plugins Manager Custom Functions]

If your encryption is more "exotic" you can use [JSR223 PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) and [commons-codec](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/) library methods.

Comment: Neither are encryption. Base64 is only an encoding, there is no security. MD5 is a weak cryptographic hash and is not secure for passwords. For a password verified an iterated one-way salted function such as PBKDF2 is needed. A proper secure password verifier is not "exotic", it is the security that is required to protect the user.

Comment: Please can someone suggest me Step By Step procedure to store the MD5 encrypted value to a variable because im a fresher to JMeter

Comment: @DeepakS Which is more important: getting MD5 to work or using a secure method to protect your users? (Yeah, kind of a trick question.)

Comment: What u said makes sense but, my requirement/task now is to encrypt the password using MD5 and add seed value to it and then again encrypt both the values using MD5.               function encPwd() {
        var seed = $("#Seed").val();
        if ($("#Password").val() != "") {
            $("#Password").val($.md5($.md5($("#Password").val()) + seed));
        }
    }

Comment: Above Function they are calling while Posting to login,As per Dmitri T comments i have used the jmeter plugin  and used MD5 function,,,but now i need the correct syntax value to Post the Password.Currently im using(
${__MD5((${__MD5(Password))+(Seed))}}) which is not working.....pls suggest me....

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into a similar problem myself: I needed to do some test queries directly on a MySQL database and the passwords were encrypted.

You can include an external Java library for handling encryption in your project, find details on how to do that on this other thread: [JMeter with Custom Java Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25150911/jmeter-with-custom-java-code)

In my case, I used jBCrypt.